# Django - would these query sets be cached?

Tags: database, django, caching, django-models

```
class UnassignedThread(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(UnassignedThread,
                self).get_queryset().filter(
                        _irc_name__isnull=True)
```

Would `results = ThreadVault.unassigned_threads.all()` be cached? I am not certain if `_isnull=True` counts as being a evaluated(since the evaluation causes the cache).

Also, if have a model called ThreadVault, and I want to look up if threads #777 and #888 exist in the database, which way is the best to utilize cache to do the look up?

```
ThreadVault.objects.get(thread_id="777")
ThreadVault.objects.get(thread_id="888")
```

or

```
results = ThreadVault.objects.all()
for ticket in results:
    if ticket.thread_id == "777" or ticket.thread_id == "888":
        do something
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, querysets are lazy until they are sliced or iterated. `filter` simply adds conditions to the query, but does not evaluate it.

For your second question, neither of these are great, although the first is vastly preferable to the second (which involves loading and iterating through every object in the table). Instead, you should use `exists()` in conjunction with an `__in` filter:

```
ThreadVault.objects.filter(thread_id__in=["777", "888"].exists()
```

Neither of these questions has anything to do with caching.

Comment: Since I need to know that if each thread id exists to add it the above won't work. Would it be more efficient to do list(ThreadVault.objects.all()) so _result_cache is full to test if each ticket number exists?

Answer (score 1):

`th_ids = ["777","888"]`

`ThreadVault.objects.filter(thread_id__in=th_ids).exists()`

### for caching your view

`from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page`

`@cache_page(60 * 15)`

`def my_view(request):`

---

---